# Adobe Reader Plugin for Google Chorme

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, zebra-printers, reader

I have a web application that sends labels in pdf to print the Zebra printer. And this PDF file just print correctly using Adobe Reader, however Google Chrome that removing the Adobe Reader plugin. I wonder if there will be some solution using new plugin architecture (PPAPI) Google Chrome.
If you can not give me this answer. Where can I get an answer on this?

Note: The Google PDF View does not print the label correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following ways to consider:

- If you control how PDF files are generated then check if they are generated properly. There could be a chance that PDF files are generated with some minor errors which are corrected by Adobe Reader but not corrected by Chrome PDF Viewer. Chrome's PDF Viewer is based on [Foxit PDF Reader](http://foxitsoftware.com/) AFAIK;
- Advise users to use Internet Explorer or Firefox instead (browsers with support for Adobe Reader plugin)
- Generate the special unique one time link that could be just copied and pasted into Internet Explorer to get the file without logging into the main site;
- Allow users to download the file so they could just open it in Adobe Reader (in case user have Adobe Reader plugin so Adobe Reader software is also available for standalone usage then).

Comment: About you suggest: - On the generation of this PDF is made by Crystal Report, I believe it is difficult to generate the same problem file, but I will test with other tools to verify that this is the problem. Do you know a PDF generation tool for Web applications to be more effective?

My client does not accept the following options:

Be a system requirement to use the the Internet Explorer or Firefox;
Create a special link to the User open and paste later in Internet Explorer or Firefox;

Comment: It really depends on the complexity of your reports. If you are looking for open source PDF generators then check these ones: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570682/PDF-File-Writer-Csharp-Class-Library-Version, https://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/, http://itextpdf.com/ (but check licensing permissions!)

Comment: I am using to generate bar codes for labels and Google Reader PDF this distorting this, so that it is printed in a way that can not be read by bar code reader.

Comment: which generetor you recommend to generate labels with code bars?

Comment: itextsharp and other libraries include barcode generation, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917809/barcode-with-text-under-using-itextsharp

Answer (score 0):

About you suggest: 
 - On the generation of this PDF is made by Crystal Report, I believe it is difficult to generate the same problem file, but I will test with other tools to verify that this is the problem. Do you know a PDF generation tool for Web applications to be more effective?

My client does not accept the following options:

- Be a system requirement to use the the Internet Explorer or Firefox;
- Create a special link to the User open and paste later in Internet Explorer or Firefox;
- Force download the pdf file so that the User can open it in Adobe;